# Passing platform specific code in libgdx - nullpointerexception

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm trying to get libgdx working with the Facebook SDK, so I figured I need to get some platform specific code running.

I started out with Android and this is my onCreate:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
    cfg.useGL20 = false;
    cfg.useAccelerometer = false;
    cfg.useCompass = false;

    initialize(new RPS(new androidFacebookHandler()), cfg);
}
```

The constructor for RPS is very simple:

```
public RPS(facebookHandler _fbhandler) {
    this.fbhandler = _fbhandler;
    this.fbhandler.test();
}
```

The test() function for fbhandler is a simple. (androidFacebookHandler implements facebookHandler)

`Gdx.app.log("debug", "test");`

However, this sample gives me a nullpointer exception... My Guess is that I can't use Gdx.app till after the initialize(). So I tried setting the fbhandler with a setFbhandler() function after the initialize(), but this gives me the same result.

Comment: So if you are using Android platform specific code, why not just: Log.i("debug, "test"); ?

Answer (score 3):

Put the call to `this.fbhandler.test();` in the `create()` method that `RPS` must have (it must be a subclass of `ApplicationListener`, right?)

In Libgdx the initialization of the library isn't complete until just before the start of the `create` method (which will be invoked by the Libgdx infrastructure to indicate that your app has started up), so you cannot access `Gdx.<anything>` until then.